# if limit of $a_n$ is $L>0$ then $a_n>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. We know that the limit of $a_n$ is $L>0$. Prove: $a_n>0$.

I know that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=L>0$, so $a_n>\frac{L}{2}>0$ for all $n>n_1$. But it does not help me because, as I understand from the question, I need to show it for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How should I prove it?

Comment: The correct statement is that $a_n > 0$ for all but finitely many terms.

Comment: @rubikscube09 Oh I see. Out of curiosity, how should I show it?

Comment: what you have written shows it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't show this result for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Consider $a_1=-1,a_n=2\forall n\ge2$. Then $L=2$ but $a_1\le0$. In fact we can always have finitely many non-positive terms.